# Ranking items in a list with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to figure out a way to rank items in a list, and hold the results in an object or another list.  I know about the orderby method, but I don't exactly know how to go about creating a corresponding rank number for each item.

For example:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

numbers.Add(650);
numbers.Add(150);
numbers.Add(500);
numbers.Add(200);
```

and then store the results  from either low to high or high to low here:

```
public class NumberRank
{
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public int Rank {get; set;}

    public NumberRank(int number)
    {
        Number = number;
        Rank = ????????;
    }
}
```

Any solutions through LINQ?

Comment: Do you need to preserve the original order?

Comment: No, just a ranking type.

Comment: Should duplicate numbers have the same rank?

Comment: @user1512559 were you able to get a solution? I am having similar challenge.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do it:

```
public class NumberRank
{
   public int Number {get; set;}
   public int Rank {get; set;}

   public NumberRank(int number, int rank)
   {
      Number = number;
      Rank = rank;
   }
}

class Test
{
   static void Main()
   {
      List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

      numbers.Add(650);
      numbers.Add(150);
      numbers.Add(500);
      numbers.Add(200);

      List<NumberRank> numberRanks = numbers.OrderByDescending(n => n).Select((n, i) => new NumberRank(n, i + 1)).ToList();

      // check it worked
      foreach(NumberRank nr in numberRanks) Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", nr.Rank, nr.Number);
      Console.ReadKey();  
   }
}
```

To rank in ascending order (i.e. lowest number first), then just replace OrderByDescending by OrderBy.

Comment: Shouldn't it duplicate ranks of same numbers? If you add **650** to the list. It results with ranks `1 2 3 ..` where it should as `1 1 3 ..`

Answer (score 18):

One of the overload of the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb534869) extension method return the index:

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form by incorporating the element's index.

You can use it to make your rank:

```
public class NumberRank
{
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public int Rank {get; set;}

    public NumberRank(int number, int rank)
    {
        Number = number;
        Rank = rank;
    }
}

List<int> numbers = new List();

numbers.Add(650);
numbers.Add(150);
numbers.Add(500);
numbers.Add(200);

numbers.OrderBy(n => n)
       .Select((n, index) => new NumberRank(n, index));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Function Rank(Of T As IComparable)(list As IEnumerable(Of T), item As T) As Integer
    Return list.Count(Function(x) x.CompareTo(item) < 0) + 1
End Function

Public Sub Main()
    Dim l = New Integer() {9, 1, 3, 8, 4, 6}
    Console.WriteLine("6 is the " & Rank(l,6) & "th element of ")
    Console.WriteLine([String].Join(" ", l))
End Sub

6 is the 4th element of
9 1 3 8 4 6
```

Or, in C# http://dotnetfiddle.net/3ZGeJ1