# How to rank elements in c# especially when it has duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, rank

I have a requirement to rank the array elements and the array has duplicate values. I tried following this [Ranking items in a list with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099452/ranking-items-in-a-list-with-linq) but this doesn't work when the array has duplicate values in it. Any easy way to do it in c#?

For Example :

```
input = [650,150,150,200] 
output = [1,3,3,2]
```

For Example :

```
input = [650,200,200,150] 
output = [1,2,2,3]
```

Update: The requirement is as below, what if I add one more element to the array
Ex: [650,150,150,200,100] output needs to be [1,3,3,2,5] instead of [1,3,3,2,4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an array of items, distinct and in order, then use the indices to determine the rank of each item.

```
var ranks = input.Distinct().OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray();
var ranked = input.Select(x => Array.IndexOf(ranks, x) + 1);
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eoJZzn)

---

**Update after comment**

If rankings need to be skipped, just remove the `Distinct`:

```
var ranks = input.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray();
var ranked = input.Select(x => Array.IndexOf(ranks, x) + 1);
```

`Array.IndexOf` will take the first element when there are duplicates.

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i6cXOH)

Comment: Update: Sorry,but my requirement is as below, what if I add one more element to the array 
Ex: [650,150,150,200,100] output needs to be [1,3,3,2,5] but this solution gives output as [1,3,3,2,4]

Answer (score 3):

You can create a dictionary as rank-lookup source:

```
int[] array = new[] {650,150,150,200};
Dictionary<int, int> numRanks = array
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
    .Select((g, index) => (num:g.Key, rank:index+1))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.num, x => x.rank);
int[] result = array.Select(i => numRanks[i]).ToArray();
```

For your updated requirement you could use a similar approach using a `Lookup<TKey, TValue>`:

```
var rankLookup = array
    .OrderByDescending(i => i)
    .Select((num, index) => (num, index))
    .ToLookup(x => x.num, x => x.index + 1);
int[] result = array.Select(i => rankLookup[i].First()).ToArray();
```

The lookup is like a dictionary that allows duplicate keys. You need to use `First` here because you are just interested in the rank. If you'd use `Count()` you'd know how many duplicates it had.

Comment: Update: Sorry, but my requirement is as below, what if I add one more element to the array 
Ex: [650,150,150,200,100] output needs to be [1,3,3,2,5] but this solution gives output as [1,3,3,2,4]

Comment: @DeepakKothari: edited my answer, but you can also use Johnathans approach